# Having problems understanding function table

Tags: functions

I am having problems understanding how to solve this question. I know the answer to the table, but do not understand the steps required to solve. Any help would be much appreciated.

<kbd>x</kbd>       <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>

<kbd>f(x)</kbd>    <kbd>-1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>10</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>

<kbd>g(x)</kbd>    <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>

<kbd>(f$o$g)(x)</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>  <kbd>?</kbd>  <kbd>?</kbd>  <kbd>?</kbd>  <kbd>?</kbd>

(**note**, answers are $10,8,-1,2,0$)

Comment: $(f\circ g) (x) := f( g(x)) $ by definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $g\circ f$ means composition of functions. I would interpret it as $g(f(x))$ **but** note that the values that $f$ takes are not all in the domain of $g$ so I suppose that the composition is in the opposite direction (and indeed the values that $g$ takes on are all in the domain of $f$), so we have:
$$(g\circ f)(x)=f(g(x).$$

Now just compute:
$$\begin{matrix}
(g\circ f)(0)=f(g(0))=f(2)=10,\\
(g\circ f)(1)=f(g(1))=f(3)=8,\\
(g\circ f)(2)=f(g(2))=f(0)=-1,\\
(g\circ f)(3)=f(g(3))=f(1)=2,\\
(g\circ f)(4)=f(g(4))=f(4)=0.\\
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Now that the OP edited the question the notation is the more conventional one (composing from the left)...

Comment: Thanks for the response, your post helped me see the pattern, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $(g\circ f)(x) = f(g(x))$.

Anyway, this is an unnatural notation used for function composition, check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

Comment: That would make $g(f(0))$ undefined (or unknown given the table above). It is probably $f(g(x))$.

Comment: @barakmanos Looks like that notation is kinda different, swap the $g$ and $f$.

Comment: I think it's you who need to swap them (at least according to the question at hand).

Comment: OK, now I can up-vote you :)